# Acquia installation is up-to-date but requests update and reports errors

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I have installed Acquia Dev Desktop in order to have a local Drupal development environment. My computer is running Windows 7. The prototype site provided with the installation appears to run fine, but there are two problems in the dashboard.

(1)
Under "Reports > Status report", the section on "Drupal core update status" is in red and says, "See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates." The words, "available updates" in that are linked. When I click that, I get "All of your projects are up to date" plus a link for "Check manually". When I click that, it works for a while and then says, "Checked available update data for 5 projects. ... All of your projects are up to date."

So Drupal both reports being up-to-date and says that there are "missing updates."

(2)
Under "Reports > Available updates", there is a red box at the top of the page with four bullets:
• Notice: Undefined index: reason in theme_update_report() (line 86 of C:...\local\DrupalDev\DrupalTest\modules\update\update.report.inc).
• Notice: Undefined index: in theme_update_report() (line 137 of C:...\local\DrupalDev\DrupalTest\modules\update\update.report.inc).
• Warning: date_timezone_set() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in format_date() (line 2040 of C:...\local\DrupalDev\DrupalTest\includes\common.inc).
• Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in format_date() (line 2050 of C:...\local\DrupalDev\DrupalTest\includes\common.inc).

Below that, under the heading, "Drupal core", there is a yellow text box. In the top right corner is a warning icon (dark yellow triangle with exclamation mark) and the box has the following text:
"Acquia Drupal 7.34.40 (Drupal 7.34 core)
Recommended version: ()
Includes: Acquia Connector, Bartik, Block, Color, Comment, Contextual links, Dashboard, Database logging, Drupal 7 driver for SQL Server and SQL Azure, Field, Field SQL storage, Field UI, File, Filter, Help, Image, List, Menu, Node, Number, Options, Overlay, Path, Pathauto, RDF, Search, Seven, Shortcut, System, Taxonomy, Text, Toolbar, Update manager, User"

===================

I found the recommendation to use Acquia Dev Desktop in three places:

www.drupal.org/node/1248034

www.drupal.org/node/263

www.drupal.org/node/1065212

which are the links in the first, second, and sixth bullets in "Local server setup" at www.drupal.org/node/157602 .

So it comes highly recommended. But the above behavior looks pretty flaky. Have I done something wrong with the installation?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the errors, I think you could continue developing your Drupal site with it but for me I wouldn't like those in my site. I myself don't know the cause of it thought but I found a recent issue in the [Acquia forum: Errors on Clean Acquia Drupal Install](https://forums.acquia.com/acquia-products-and-services/acquia-cloud/errors-clean-acquia-drupal-install-0) which still has no reply on a fix.

**Option 1: Use Acquia**

Try uninstalling and reinstalling the whole Acquia Dev software and see if the issue still persists.

**Option 2: Use XAMPP(I use)/WAMPP**

I've been using this since I started web and its straight forward. You don't need to change any settings too. What you need to do is:

1. Download the .exe from the [XAMPP page](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)
2. Install the application
3. Download Drupal Core that can be downloaded [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal)
4. Extract Drupal Core into C:/xampp/htdocs/[your drupal root folder] (if you just chose the default settings of XAMPP on installation)
5. Go to http://localhost/phpmyadmin and create your database there, just use the defaults too
6. Start the installation of your Drupal site by going to http://localhost/your-drupal-root-folder-name]

Comment: I did what you suggested and I like XAMPP a lot more than Dev Desktop. I have a new problem with the XAMPP implementation. If you get a chance, perhaps you could take a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154186/xampp-apache-virtual-host-not-working .

Comment: That's great! Glad you're starting to like it too. Sure! I'll take a look at it.